# Linux API / library to enumerate all listening ports of a specific IP

Tags: c, linux, networking, kernel, port

What options are available for enumerating all listening ports of a specific IP on Linux?

The prototype of the function I am looking for is something like:

```
enumerateListeners : IP -> [Port]
```

either a kernel API or C library would be really interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/proc` filesystem is the kernel interface that you can use to obtain this information. TCP sockets in particular are listed in `/proc/net/tcp` and in `/proc/net/tcp6`. The second column gives the local address as an IP:port pair. To pick those sockets that are in LISTEN state you have to look at those that have `0A` in the `st` (socket state) column. Here's an example of what I've got:

```
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode                                                     
   0: 00000000:3E81 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000  1000        0 18064 1 0000000000000000 100 0 0 10 0                     
   1: 00000000:1269 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000  1000        0 18056 1 0000000000000000 100 0 0 10 0                     
   2: 0100007F:0CEA 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000   117        0 13084 1 0000000000000000 100 0 0 10 0                     
   3: 00000000:008B 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 9097 1 0000000000000000 100 0 0 10 0                      
   4: 0100007F:0050 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 14349 1 0000000000000000 100 0 0 10 0
```

Reading this file is simple in C: open it and go over it with `fscanf`.

If there's another way to obtain this information I don't know it; this is the interface that `netstat` uses too, as you can easily verify with `strace`.

Comment: I have written my own answer following a solution similar to your first suggestion. Would you mind taking a look especially at the use of `sscanf` for possible issues?

Comment: @CetinSert see the Linux kernel, `http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/+code=raw_sock_seq_show` (sorry, can't link, SO's parser mangles the URL) for the `printf()` format expression. You should be able to reverse that via `scanf()`.

Comment: @FrankH. Thanks a lot! Each link to its sources takes me one step closer to becoming a kernel module / kernel developer :)! I have come up with something that works you can see below in my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

```
#include <stdio.h>          // printf, fopen, fclose
#include <stdlib.h>         // free
#include <arpa/inet.h>      // in_addr*

#define OK(x) ((x) > -1)
#define LISTENING (0x0A)
#define port u_int16_t

int listening(in_addr_t addr, port* ports, size_t nPorts) {

  char* line = NULL; size_t n = 0;
  u_int32_t locaddr; u_int32_t locport; u_int32_t state; int i = 0;
  FILE* tcp = fopen("/proc/net/tcp", "r");

  if   (!OK(getline(&line, &n, tcp))) goto f;
  while (OK(getline(&line, &n, tcp)) && i < nPorts) {
    int r = sscanf(line, "%*d: %8x:%4x %*8x:%*4x %2x", &locaddr, &locport, &state);
    if (r == 3 && addr == locaddr && state == LISTENING) ports[i++] = (port)locport;
  }

  f: fclose(tcp); free(line); return i;
}

int main(int c, char* a[]) {
  struct in_addr ipv4; inet_pton(AF_INET, a[1], &ipv4);     printf("%i = ", ipv4.s_addr);
  char str[512];       inet_ntop(AF_INET, &ipv4, str, 512); printf("%s\n" , str);

  port pts[65536]; printf("{ listening: [ "); c = listening(ipv4.s_addr, pts, 65536);
  int i; for (i = 0; i < c; i++) printf("%i, ", pts[i]); printf("] }\n");
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are not setting `*line` to NULL, so `getline` may write over random memory instead of allocating a new buffer. The rest looks good, one thing though: if the file format is ever changed it's probably done by adding new columns, so your best bet for future safety is to ignore the end of the line once you have found the data you need.

Comment: @Joni, updated to show only those in state `0A` and integrate your suggestions with regards to `getline` and minimizing assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

So, Are you asking for a PortScanner?
The best PortScanner that I know is  [Nmap](http://nmap.org/).

You could take a look to its source code, otherwise writing a *simple* function that enumerates TCP ports open for a specific IP is not an hard issue, you could use *connect* function together with a for loop.

Comment: No, I am not looking for something to scan remote IPs. Rather for the C equivalent of the PERL answer provided here to enumerate local listening ports: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12107348/112882.